# How to use a semaphore from a specific thread to play/pause a lot of other threads?

Tags: c, semaphore

It is pritty clear my need.

I have a "Manager" thread that needs to manage a kind of "Signal" with ON/OFF values.

When this Manager set the Signal = ON, I want that many threads that are running and paused(maybe WAIT(SIGNAL)) in their codes be able to move on and execute until the "Manager" thread put the Signal = OFF again.

Is this "signal" a semaphore? What type of semaphore? How do I need to initialize it and where?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe this is a language barrier problem, but semaphores can't be "from a specific thread."  They're shared among all threads that care to use them.  If you have N threads to control, then you have a choice of using N binary (signal/wait) semaphores shared pairwise between the controlling and controlled threads or a single counting semaphore shared among all threads. To allow K threads to proceed, the controller sets the counter to K.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for replying! Forget the semaphore thing so. I have multiple threads (the quantity of them is uncertain because depends on runtime execution). I want to pause/play this threads on demand by entering some commands in the console of a process. I though that one shared semaphore (like a barrier) could be the solution

Comment: You might want to read https://sworthodoxy.blogspot.com/2015/05/shared-resource-design-patterns.html

Comment: Mmm It seems that doesn't apply to my needs. Besides, I need an ANSI C solution. I'm not a very experienced programmer.

Comment: Well, thread control is not exactly a topic for an inexperienced programmer.  There are only a few ways that a thread can block (temporarily halt execution).  They all involve making a system call that allows the OS to de-schedule the thread until some later time.  Semaphores are one option.  Waiting threads are unblocked with another system call (by a different thread) that changes the semaphores' value (which is either boolean or an integer). Another is i/o. A thread makes a call to read or write, and the thread blocks until that's done. In that case, it's the OS that wakes the waiter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in comments, thread control is tricky. C-level synchronization primitives are - as all things in C - low-level. You'll need to build the management from there.

Here is one rough sketch of a method that uses one mutex and one signal/wait variable per running thread.

Many things you'd want in a production app are missing here: reusing thread table entries, resource cleanup, proper waiting for final termination, etc. But it's a starting point.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>

typedef enum { RUNNING, WAITING, KILLED } STATE;

typedef struct {
  int id;
  STATE state;
  pthread_t thread[1];
  pthread_mutex_t mutex[1];
  pthread_cond_t cond[1];
} CONTROLLED_THREAD;

void* poll_for_work(void *env) {
  CONTROLLED_THREAD *ct = env;
  while (1) {
    pthread_mutex_lock(ct->mutex);
    if (ct->state == KILLED) break;
    if (ct->state == WAITING) pthread_cond_wait(ct->cond, ct->mutex);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(ct->mutex);
    
    printf("Thread %d is working!\n", ct->id);
    sleep(3);
  }
  pthread_mutex_unlock(ct->mutex);
  return NULL;
}

void make_thread(CONTROLLED_THREAD *ct, int id) {
  ct->id = id;
  ct->state = RUNNING;
  pthread_mutex_init(ct->mutex, NULL);
  pthread_cond_init(ct->cond, NULL);
  pthread_create(ct->thread, NULL, poll_for_work, ct);
}

void kill_thread(CONTROLLED_THREAD *ct) {
  pthread_mutex_lock(ct->mutex);
  ct->state = KILLED;
  pthread_mutex_unlock(ct->mutex);
}

void pause_thread(CONTROLLED_THREAD *ct) {
  pthread_mutex_lock(ct->mutex);
  if (ct->state == RUNNING) ct->state = WAITING;
  pthread_mutex_unlock(ct->mutex);
}

void run_thread(CONTROLLED_THREAD *ct) {
  pthread_mutex_lock(ct->mutex);
  if (ct->state == WAITING) {
     ct->state = RUNNING;
     pthread_cond_signal(ct->cond);
  }
  pthread_mutex_unlock(ct->mutex);
}

int main(void) {
  char *buf = malloc(100);
  size_t len;
  int n = 0, current_id = 0, id;
  CONTROLLED_THREAD threads[100];

  while (1) {
    getline(&buf, &len, stdin);
    if (strncmp(buf, "new", 3) == 0) {
      make_thread(threads + n++, ++current_id);
    } else if (strncmp(buf, "kill", 4) == 0 && sscanf(buf + 4, "%d", &id) == 1) {
      for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        if (threads[i].id == id) {
          kill_thread(threads + i);
          break;
        }
      }
    } else if (strncmp(buf, "pause", 5) == 0) {
      for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) pause_thread(threads + i);
    } else if (strncmp(buf, "run", 3) == 0) {
      for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) run_thread(threads + i);
    } else {
      printf("unknown command %s\n", buf);
    }
  }
  free(buf);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks!! I will try something like that and see how it works!